# Skype4Py SendMessage not working in windows

Tags: skype4py

I have installed Skype4Py on windows and trying to call functions mentioned in skype.py that is library of Skype4Py.

It is giving me current user's full name, handle and other informations properly. Even I am able to call to my friend via the python script.

The issue is in sending message to my Skype friend. Using below command to send message to friend:

```
skype = Skype4Py.Skype()
skype.SendMessage(user.handle, 'May I help you!!!')
```

but it is throwing arror as below:

```
 raise SkypeError(int(errnum), errstr)
Skype4Py.errors.SkypeError: [Errno 508] CHAT: CREATE: opening a dialog to the given user failed
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out in the [Skype FAQs](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12384/how-does-my-3rd-party-application-work-with-skype-and-how-will-changes-to-skype-impact-my-3rd-party-application) they explain that sending messages is no longer allowed for a 3rd party app, forcing you to use their own version.

> "As communicated in this blog post, due to technology improvements we are making to the Skype experience, some features of the API will stop working with Skype for desktop. For example, delivery of chat messages using the API will cease to work. However, we are happy to share that we will be extending support for two of the most widely used features – call recording and compatibility with hardware devices – until we determine alternative options or retire the current solution."

Hence I don't think Skype4Py's messaging function will work at all on Skype for desktop.

Apparently:

> "We value the input of our developers and users as we continue to improve the Skype experience."